# Find text using Xpath with class (vb.net)

Tags: visualstudio, xpath

**Hey guys !**
This is on what I'm working on :

```
 Dim url As String = "http://brayket.byethost9.com/index.php?/shoutbox/"
    Dim web As New HtmlWeb()
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = web.Load(url)
    Dim names As HtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='shoutbox_text']")
    Console.WriteLine(names)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000000)
```

I'd like to write on the console everything that's between "`<span class="shoutbox_text">`" and `</span>`
Hope I'll find some help here :)

Comment: Have you tried `Console.WriteLine(names.InnerText)`?

Comment: @MarcusRickert I don't have the possibility

I know that it works because if I do `console.writeline(names.count)` it shows the right amount of span class"shoutbox_text" in the html code. But I can't manage to show what are these classes >< 

(By the way, I'm using HtmlAglityPack)

Comment: I've managed to make it work ! 

This is what I've done :

`code`Dim web As New HtmlWeb()
        Dim doc As HtmlDocument = web.Load(url)

        Dim row = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class=""row2""]")
for each xName in row
console.writeline(xName.innertext)`code`

And it works :)

Comment: @Niiw - could you post your solution as an answer, then accept it? That way the solution will be more clear to others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Dim url As String = "http://brayket.byethost9.com/index.php?/shoutbox/"
    Dim web As New HtmlWeb()
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = web.Load(url)
    Dim names As HtmlNodeCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='shoutbox_text']")

'**Place the code below to read each values between selected nodes.**

For Each useAnyWantedWordHere in names
console.writeline(userAnyWantedWord.InnerText & vbcrlf)
Next
Console.ReadLine()
```

If you want to make it work with a textbox or richtextbox this is the code :

```
For Each AnyWantedWord in names
richtextbox1.AppendText(AnyWantedWord.InnerText & vbCrLF)
Next
```